# Cordova based apk installion & developed file location

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am now learning cordova and i wanna know something.

Example, I have index.html & index.js in my cordova project.
I will build app and install it in my phone.

So the question is those two files index.html & index.js will be in app package folder inside phone local storage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the files show up in a hidden area on Android and iOS.  Anyone with a rooted phone can see them.  Don't store security keys in your code.

All Cordova really is is on Android and iOS is a reference to the embedded browser available on both systems and hook to load whatever page you specify in the config.xml.  You can even set the config.xml starting file to be your webpack dev server.  Therefore your html and JS files have to exist somewhere for the web browser to open them.

Comment: Trevor
Thanks for answering
and i wanna know something.

Example

I have login.html with ajax code.

Who ever can browse / able to check login.html can also able to something bad if he/she is skillful.

Therefore how do i prevent them from doing bad thing or hacking to web service / web api ?

Comment: @PyayPhyoKyaw Well if they did that, they could see how to send data to your web API, but not the actual login.  And they can't hack other peoples phones, just their own.  So like any other website, never trust the client. Make sure all your web apis including login sanitize their inputs, watch for overflows, sql injection, etc.  All the same things you would do for a normal website.  And use SSL.  The real trick is what to do when the user wants to save their login in their phone.  For my app, I encrypt the password and login and store to an sqlite database